# How do i set check-boxes checked on particular Value using JSTL?

Tags: spring, jsp, checkbox, jstl

I am using JSTL and multiple check-boxes, i just want to checked some check-boxes by default

```
<form:checkboxes path="userName" items="${UserList}" id="userName" class="check-margin-top"/>
```

and I am doing like this

```
<form:checkboxes path="userName" items="${UserList}" id="userName"class="check-margin-top"
<c:forEach var='list' items="${UserList}"> 
<c:if test="${list == '1'}"checked="checked"></c:if>
</c:forEach>
></form:checkboxes>
```

And i am getting UserList like this
{ 4 = A,11 = DUMMY,9 = Test,5 = John Smith,6 = kp
}
i want to keep checked to 9 and 5 now what should i do ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer to your question.

> Generate a runtime list for the checkboxes value, and link it to Spring’s form tag `<form:checkboxes>`

```
//SimpleFormController...
protected Map referenceData(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    Map referenceData = new HashMap();
    List<String> userList= new ArrayList<String>();
    webFrameworkList.add("John");
    webFrameworkList.add("Smith");
    webFrameworkList.add("Doe");
    webFrameworkList.add("Peter");
    referenceData.put("userList", userList);

    return referenceData;
}
```

> Checked by default…
>   If you want to make 2 checkboxes with value “John” and “Smith” are checked by default, you can initialize the “favUser” property with value “John” and “Smith”. For example :

```
//SimpleFormController...
        @Override
protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request)
    throws Exception {

    User user = new User();
    user .setFavUser(new String []{"John","Smith"});

    return user ;
}
```

> User.java

```
public class User{

    String [] favUser;
    //getter & setter

}
```

> your checkboxes should be

```
<form:checkboxes items="${userList}" path="favUser" />
```

> Note

```
<form:checkboxes items="${dynamic-list}" path="property-to-store" />
```

> For multiple checkboxes, as long as the “path” or “property” value is
>   equal to any of the “checkbox values – ${dynamic-list}“, the matched
>   checkbox will be checked automatically.

from https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-checkbox-and-checkboxes-example/