# how to get checked checkboxes jstl

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, jstl

i am performing crud operation using Spring MVC with hibernate. And using JSTL for front end. I am displaying checked checkboxes with corresponding database values. but they doesn't  check if my corresponding database values are more than one. if i have only one value in database then the corresponding checkbox got checked.

I am using JSTL tag library and mapping with model attribute as shown in below code.

**Index.html**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
    <c:url var="resourceURL" value="/resources" />
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <style>
    .error {
        color: red;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="userLogin">
            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td>hobby</td>
                    <td>cricket<form:checkbox path="hobby" value="cricket" />
                        soccer<form:checkbox path="hobby" value="soccer" /> 
                        tennis<form:checkbox path="hobby" value="tennis" /> 
                        hockey<form:checkbox path="hobby" value="hockey" />
                    </td>
                    <td><form:errors path="hobby" cssClass="error" /></td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="update"></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </form:form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**MainController.java**

```
    package com.test.controller;

    import javax.validation.Valid;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
    import com.test.domain.UserLogin;
    import com.test.service.UserLoginService;


    @Controller
    public class MainController {

        @Autowired
        private UserLoginService uls;

        @GetMapping
        public String landingIndex(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("userLogin", new UserLogin());
            return new String("index");
        }

        @PostMapping
        public String insertingValue(@ModelAttribute @Valid UserLogin userLogin01, BindingResult result) {
            if(result.hasErrors()) {
                return new String("index");
            }else {
                uls.saveUser(userLogin01);
            } 
            return new String("redirect:/home");
        }

        @GetMapping("/home")
        public ModelAndView redirectingToHome(){
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("Home");
            mv.addObject("userList",uls.fetchingUsersDetails());
            return mv;
        }

        @GetMapping("/delete")
        public String deleteUserName(@ModelAttribute UserLogin userLogin){
            uls.deletingUser(userLogin);
            return new String("redirect:/home");
        }

        @GetMapping("/update")
        public ModelAndView updateUserName(@ModelAttribute UserLogin userLogin,Model model){
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
            model.addAttribute("userLogin", uls.fetchingUserDetailThroughId(userLogin));
            return mv;
        }
    }
```

**DaoImpl.java**

```
    package com.test.daoimpl;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
    import com.test.dao.UserLoginDao;
    import com.test.domain.UserLogin;

    @Repository
    @Transactional
    public class UserLoginDaoImpl implements UserLoginDao{

        @Autowired(required = true)
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        public void saveUser(UserLogin ul) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(ul);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public List<UserLogin> fetchingUsersDetails() {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(UserLogin.class).list();
        }

        @Override
        public void deletingUser(UserLogin ul) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(ul);
        }

        @Override
        public UserLogin fetchingUserDetailThroughId(UserLogin ul) {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(UserLogin.class,ul.getId());
        }
    }





     **output**
```

in the database,hobbies are inserted as follow -
    cricket,soccer,hockey

but at the time of update i didn't get any checked box. but if i have only one hobby in database then the corresponding database checked.

Comment: what type is `UserLogin#hobby` property?

Comment: its String hobby;

Comment: jstl matches the exact value which means if the value in db is `cricket` then the checkbox with the value `cricket` will be checked, if the value in db is `cricket,soccer,hockey` then no checkbox will be checked as no checkbox has value `cricket,soccer,hockey`

Comment: yes Valentine Carnu, is there any way to solve it

Comment: The answer from [How do i set check-boxes checked on particular Value using JSTL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40167560/10386912) thread could be a solution. To summarize convert the multivalues string into a list by splitting it by coma and use the list property in jstl